# Is it possible to take down enemy recon planes?

Tags: call-of-duty-ww2

I know Mountain division members, at rank II, get immunity to enemy Recon planes.   But for all the other classes, that seem to have no way to counter recon planes, is there a way for them to take down UAV planes?

In Black Ops 1 you could use a SAM Launcher killstreak to take down enemy aircraft, including UAVs, or use guided launchers to take them down. Given there is no lock on in World War II, is it still possible to take down a recon plane while it is doing recon?

Comment: I can't remember in World At War if you were able to use an LMG to shoot them down, of if they were invisible in that game.  Have you tried shooting at it? Does a hit box appear?

Comment: There is no lock on but the M1 bazooka specifically says it's an anti aircraft launcher. If you lead the planes you can take them out with a rocket

Comment: After actually trying to shoot down planes with a rocket I'm gonna say that's a no go. Not sure why you get an anti aircraft launcher if it's so damn hard to actually hit with it.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill it's possible.  I do it all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, yes, it's possible to shoot down enemy recon planes. According to users in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/WWII/comments/6w00nd/psa_you_are_allowed_to_shoot_down_recon_planes/), it's fairly easy to do with an LMG.

> Look up into the sky and find the Recon Plane. Shoot at it. Get enough shots on it and it will go down.

---

> It takes like 15 shots max with the LMGs to knock em out. And you get 150 points for doing so, that goes a long way towards streaks

---

> I'm an LMG guy and that's what I've been doing. Big points.

---

> I always knock them down, very easy with the M1 Garand. Others don't seem to bother lol

Answer (score 9):

Beyond the accepted answer, it is possible to also shoot down enemy recon planes with the M1 Bazooka - 1 hit kill (and possibly other launchers, however no personal experience with these). Lead in is required.

Comment: This should probably be a comment because it adds a minor detail.

Comment: Unable to place a comment without 50 rep

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with the M1-Bazooka, as it is accurate enough to effectively lead the aircraft by some margin, or in other words shoot at where it is going to be in a few moments, and take it down. This does take practice, but once you learn how it is very easy to switch to whatever class has the M1 equipped, and take down the aircraft. It is also possible to use the Panzerschreck, but as this rocket is very inacurate (just fire it into the air and watch the spiral trail of smoke) it is better to use the Bazooka.

If you prefer to use a regular gun there is a weapon attachment that increases damage through surfaces and damage dealt to enemy scorestreaks that may prove useful.

Answer (score 0):

The M1 Bazooka works just fine to take down a recon aircraft, but you have to lead the target and aim with the top sight - not the middle hole. Once you figure that out it's easy, it goes exactly where you expect it to go and flies completely straight.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 ways to take it down. I can confirm the first 4 are effective (have not yet had success with #5).

1. Counter-recon streak: A fighter will fly in and take it out (could take a few seconds). Easy, no effort beyond calling in the streak.
2. Flak Gun streak: Anti-aircraft guns will shoot it down (pretty quickly). Easy, no effort beyond calling in the streak.
3. Fighter Pilot streak: If you can target the recon plane, you can take it out. Trickier than the other streaks, and easier if you have a recon plane to show the enemy plane on your map. If you target the edge of the map in the path of the plane it will end up in your line of fire and you can take it out.
4. Rocket launcher. The M1 Bazooka and Panzerschreck can both take out the recon plane, but might require a bit of practice to do right. You need to aim a bit ahead of the plane.
5. LMG fire. Probably the most difficult. Can be difficult to get enough hits in before it flies off, especially with recoil (and enemy fire).